# How to display filename existing in 2 directories using python?

Tags: python, file, directory

Display filename existing in 2 directories using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use listdir from os:

```
import os
first_files = os.listdir('first folder')
second_files = os.listdir('second folder')
matches = [x for x in second_files if x in first_files]
print(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the file names from both directories into an array and compare them against each other to see if there is a match